# Dealing with Cache Misses and 'no-cache' Directives in amzn CloufFront

Tags: caching, next.js, amazon-cloudfront

I'm currently working on a Next.js application where certain pages have cache headers set to `cache-control: no-cache, max-age=120, must-revalidate`. Despite this configuration, I'm consistently experiencing cache misses from CloudFront. From my research, I understand that 'no-cache' instructs the CDN to verify the freshness of the content with the origin server before serving it. Does this imply that my origin server is communicating that the resource is stale and must be updated?

Comment: Your directives are contradictory, as setting 'no-cache` is approximately equivalent to setting `max-age=0`. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry No cahce, as far as I coud find out, does not mean "do not cache". But rather that the edge must revalidate with origin. But I may be mistaken

Comment: No need to guess, [RFC 9111](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9111) explains exactly what these directives mean. When a stored resource is no longer fresh the cache will revalidate with the origin server. That's true in either case, it's not unique to `no-cache`. The question is how long the cache can use the resource *before* doing that revalidation. `no-cache` has a freshness time of 0 (revalidate every time), `max-age=120` has a freshness time of 120 (revalidate after 2 minutes). Hence, these are in conflict.

Answer (score 0):

`no-cache` & `max-age=120` are contradictory in general, and for CloudFront.

`no-cache` indicates that the content should not be served from cache without revalidation. `max-age=120` indicates that the content can be cached & served for a maximum of 120 seconds before being revalidated.

These are 2 different things.

If you want to set a maximum age for caching, remove `no-cache` and `must-revalidate` from the header and just use `cache-control: max-age=120`.

If you want strict revalidation on every request, use `cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate` without specifying a `max-age`.